# Cassia TS libraries rporting false session login time (sometimes...)

Tags: c#, terminal-services

Is anyone familiar with Cassia Terminal Service libraries?  I’m having problems with the login times.

On some PCs the time is about seven minutes later than it should be.  I read that there was a similar bug, but was corrected.

I have a service running under LocalSystem, which reports for example `12:07:10`, but I know the user logged in at `12:00:00`. Looking in the event log, verifies the time.  Terminal server manager and Hyena also show the correct login time.

If I remotely query that machine, using the same libraries and methods, I get the correct login time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to [issue 20](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/issues/detail?id=20), which has been fixed on the Cassia trunk. The trunk is quite stable, so if you'd like, you can grab the latest build from the [build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project51) (login as a guest and use the artifacts link) and give it a shot. If you have any issues with the latest build, you can add a comment to the issue.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I assumed, getting the latest release would have all the "current" files.  Can I just get the latest files from the Code.Google page?  I have nothing against "TeamCity", but yet another site with registration....  I will look into it later, and post my results.

Comment: Dan Port... I didn't realize, you are the author. Sorry about that!  I find your libraries very usefull. Thank you for making my life easier ;-).  I needed something to use that a service could get info about logged in users.  The TS API seemed the best, but how to use it in C#.  As a rank beginner, I wouldn't have had a chance.

Comment: I'm glad you found the library useful. I forgot to mention that you don't have to register to access the build server -- you can just click the "Login as a Guest" link -- but you have probably figured that out already! I'll update my answer nonetheless.